# Error Code 2318 While Installing Bluestack

Tags: uninstallation, bluestacks

I have receive `error code 2318` while i installed a `bluestack` in my computer.

I have already installed a bluestack but i delete installed folder.

And i tried to uninstall bluestack software from my laptop but it generate `2318` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answer.

Generally delete all registry from your computer.

Open your computer's registry (Enter `regedit` in run) and find (alt+F) `bluestack` and delete all registry then try to install bluestack in your computer.